# Should I store len(list) somewhere?

Tags: python

code1:

```
list=[1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(len(list)):
    for j in range(len(list)):
        print(i+j)
```

code2:

```
list=[1,2,3,4,5]
l=len(list)
for i in range(l):
    for j in range(l):
        print(i+j)
```

Dose code2 faster than code1?

Comment: The fact that you do not add two elements together in the second one of course will have impact :) The two fragments do different work so it does not make sense to compare these.

Comment: Try it and tell us :)
Run both variations just use a larger list, time it, and tell us the result

Comment: There is no way you can feel the difference in speed in your case!

Comment: Furthermore there are two strange things here: you name the list `list`, and you do not fetch the value of that index, you only process the indices. Usually if you iterate over a  list, it is both more efficient and idiomatic to perform `for element in the_list:`

Comment: You shouldn't use `list` as a variable name: it will shadow the `list` class, preventing you from calling the `list` constructor (useful for casting) and from extending the `list` class.

Answer (score 13):

There will be no noticeable difference. `len(somelist)` is a very fast [O(1)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) operation. Lists have their length stored internally, so there's very little work to be done when you ask a list for its length.

Comment: In addition to this, storing the result of `len` in an external variable is error-prone and unsemantic. It increases code complexity and cognitive overhead with no benefit. The programmer has to remember that any modifications to the list might make the cached length stale. There is no real convention for how such a cached `len()` variable should be named, adding another layer of indirection to understanding the code, not to mention the extra line of code added. Caching `len` is [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) at best and at worst, it's a nasty bug.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question in the title:

> Should I store `len(list)` somewhere?

Obtaining the length of a list requires *O(1)* time and is usally quite fast. In your first code fragment you will obtain the length of the list *O(n)* times, but this is *not significant* compared to the *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* time complexity of the algorithm.

Strictly speaking we can of course not know the time complexity of calculating the length of a list (since any Python interpreter might do it differently). But the most popular interpreter *CPython* uses the [following datastructure](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1a5856bf9295fa73995898d576e0bedf016aee1f/Include/listobject.h#L23):

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    PyObject **ob_item;
    Py_ssize_t allocated;
} PyListObject;
```

It holds a field `allocated` that stores the number of cells that are occupied that can be retrieved in constant time.

Your program is however strange in the sense that you iterate over the indices of the list, and not over the *elements* of the list. In case you want to process the elements, it is both more elegant and efficient to use:

```
# processing the elements of the list:

some_list = [1,4,2,5]

for elem1 in some_list:
    for elem2 in some_list:
        print(elem1+elem2)
```

Finally I would like to add that Python was not really designed to be the most efficient programming environment there is. Python has chosen programmer's convenience over speed (since the rationale is that *development time* is more costly than *processing time*). So if obtaining the length of a list several times, is really a key issue, Python is probably not the good choice to process your list to begin with. In that case you better make use of libraries like `numpy` that are designed to do processing in batch. These libraries interface some array processing functions to Python, but do the processing itself in a more efficient environment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, because len() is a very cheap operation, you can easily check it:

```
$ cat code1.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python3

for x in range(10000):
    list=[1,2,3,4,5]
    for i in range(len(list)):
        for j in range(len(list)):
            print(i+j)

$ cat code2.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python3

for x in range(10000):
    list=[1,2,3,4,5]
    l=len(list)
    for i in range(l):
        for j in range(l):
            print(i)

$ time ./code1.py >> /dev/null 

real    0m0.153s
user    0m0.152s
sys 0m0.000s

$ time ./code2.py >> /dev/null 

real    0m0.156s
user    0m0.152s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Answer (score -2):

*yes code2 is faster than code 1*

`reason is in code 1 each time you are calculating len which means you are calculating length **0(len(list)*len(list))** where in code 2 you area calculating only one time length of list here is **o(len(list)**.`

```
def abc():
    list=[1,2,3,4,5]
    for i in range(len(list)):
        for j in range(len(list)):
            print(i+j)

def mmm():
    list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    l = len(list)
    for i in range(l):
        for j in range(l):
            print(i + j)

from time import time
t0 = time()
abc()
t1 = time()
mmm()
t2 = time()

print 'function1  takes %f' %(t1-t0)
print 'function2 takes %f' %(t2-t1)
```

output:

```
function1  takes 0.000091
function2 takes 0.000065
```

Comment: Your statement is incorrect. You calculate the length *O(n)* times in the first code fragment, and you do it *O(1)* time in the second. Note that the `range(..)` is constructed once when we enter a `for` loop.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how can you say for million of numbers in list it calculates the length of list in o(1) ,do you know the internals of python how they calculate length of list

Comment: yes, it simply stores the number of elements. See [here](https://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-list-implementation/).

Comment: Furthermore please do not use `time`. `time` measures **wall** time, not **user time**.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Cool stuff do you have any links or notes for this deepness in python to know about